# Get RGB/Web color values for Avery vinyl colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color, vinyl

I'm doing some basic web-design work pro-bono for a local charity, and I'm trying to match some colors that they use on the side of their vehicles.  They use Avery vinyl in two colors and a 3m reflective tape: Medium blue SC 900-655-O, Light Blue SC-900-640, and 3M 680-64.

Now, I know the 3M tape is reflective, so I'll probably never exactly match that color, but what about the two Avery colors?  I haven't found anything on the web that gives me RGB values, or even CMYK values.  I've thought about pulling the values from Avery's color selector PDF, but I don't have very much confidence in those colors.

Anybody got any tricks to help me with this one?

Comment: I wouldnt put myself in that position.  I would request the client to choose a color

Comment: Yes, if the client doesn't care or can't spec them, just use your eyes.